# Page not found - show other possibles. Return 404 or 301?

Tags: http, seo, user-experience

If a users follows a dead link to my site and requests a record which is no longer valid I would like to be able to provide them with a list of other potential records which they might have been searching for. Most of my records get "soft" deleted so I am normally able to derive search data from the ID in the request - but never the new ID of the record (records can be moved but there is no link between the old a new records, other records may simply not exist any more).

My gut instinct is to return a page of content with the possible records along with a 404 header to hopefully get search engines to drop the index for that URL.

The other option would be to redirect (301 - or even 303??) to this results page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advocate a status code of `300` to indicate multiple choices (per [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html))

Answer (score 1):

If you have one target to redirect to, use a 301 to redirect to it.

If you have multiple options, I would go with a 300 - it indicates multiple choices.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should go with the 404, since you stated you provide a **list** with **multiple** items. A redirect should be used with one possible item only.

update: I totally forgot about 300... use that one as mentioned before by Rowland Shaw

Answer (score -1):

By "records" - do you mean vinyl?

For the "SEO" tag in your question - if you're running an eCommerce store and driving traffic keep the 200 OK and display the record as (permanently) out-of-stock (as you suggest) and offer alternate "records" - never drop an indexed product link for a "good" product.

I'd only advocate a "301 Permanent Redirect" if the product is genuinely damaging to your site / business.

For the "user-experience" - again keep the 200 OK - the user doesn't care what status is being returned.

Comment: why the -1 please? IMO this is SEO 101.